# String search by a fixed text and * wildcard

Tags: vba, excel

I have some files in a folder that are named "Panel Countries_15.05" and "Non-Panel Countries_15.05", the date will change according to month, and I'm trying to target open these files regarding the month that will be. The problem is when I'm trying to open the "Panel Countries"(alone) it will open the "Non-Panel Countries". Is there a way to search after a fix text and then a wildcard?:

```
directory = "C:\Users\calin.lencar\Desktop\Feasibility & Capacity\Raw Data\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*Panel countries*.xlsx")

directory = "C:\Users\calin.lencar\Desktop\Feasibility & Capacity\Raw Data\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*Non-panel countries*.xlsx")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should remove first `*` from `"*Panel countries*.xlsx`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks!